# Animating Depth of field - not smooth change of focus

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, depth-of-field

I've been trying to animate simple change of focus between background or foregroud. Everything should be fine, but for some reason focus change is not fluid - it looks like its changing depth of field amount every few frames instead of doing it slowly every frame.
I use eevee as my renderer, i've tried keyframing focus distance but also setting an empty and animating its position.
Do you have any idea how to approach this problem?